# Button method seems to be overridden?

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I start at activity A, which contains two buttons, which take you to activities B and C respectively. While in either activity B or C, there is a timer: once the timer expires you are taken back to activity A by the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(B_or_C.this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Once I am back in activity A, however, something weird happens. Tapping the button for B brings me to activity C, or vice versa, though only occasionally. Sometimes tapping the button brings me to the correct activity and sometimes it doesn't. I've tried using both onClickListeners and onClick(View view) as means of settings what happens when a button is pressed, but in both cases, after the above code is run, there is a chance that tapping a button will bring me to the wrong activity.

Is there any way to definitively set what happens when a button is tapped?

EDIT: Tried adding the `final` modifier to the onClick methods, even so, sometimes tapping on Button B gets me to activity C. I don't understand why this would happen, the onClick method of button B contains only the following:

```
public final void onClickB(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Why would clicking this button ever bring me to C.class, which it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, why don't you create intent the standard way, and also, I think you want to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP instead of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B_or_C.this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

//quit current activity
finish();
```

Additionally, in both cases, add finish() after you start your intent to finish current activity, eg:

```
public final void onClickB(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    //add finish() to quit current activity
    finish();
}
```

Also, you might consider linking button B or C click action with onBackPressed(), this way you will rely on Android to go to previous activity.

Read the docs on tasks and back stack [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

in your ActivityB or C do that instead of restarting ActivityA

```
 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
 finish();
```